# Select data from logged in user with a mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have some nodes, those nodes belongs to a company. Users that belong to a company can only view the nodes.

[image: Portion of the database and wished relations]

The MySQL query I'm trying to use is this:

```
SELECT nodes.mac, companys.companyName FROM users, nodes, companys WHERE users.id='2' AND nodes.owner=users.company
```

It almost works - it shows one node for every user. I want to show only `$_SESSION` user nodes.

Comment: `$_SESSION` either provides you with a user id or it is also a table in the database where you can lookup the user id. (I only know SQL and not the PHP specifics.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `INNER JOIN` to find nodes for single user like this way using `ON` and `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT nodes.mac, 
  companys.companyName FROM users 
INNER JOIN companys ON 
 users.company=companys.id
INNER JOIN nodes ON 
 companys.id=nodes.owner WHERE 
 users.id=2
```

Here user.id should be `$_SESSION` array value that will contains your current user's id